# get fields with spaces with awk in one column

Tags: bash, awk

I have these data:

```
1   GNFJCOLT   INPET99999   SDFDSFSFLFSDFFFD9ETwAyDMDIxLjA0LjEyLjE1LjFwAA==
2   PARAINIT                SDFFFtLmlibS50d3Mub2JqZWN0cy5wbGFuDSFIxLDxLjAwADE1FAA==
```

Like you see, sometimes column three don't have any data. I'm trying to get values of every line field 4th like these:

```
cat file | awk  -F '[[:space:]][[:space:]][[:space:]]' '{ print $4}' .
```

It gives me:

```
SDFDSFSFLFSDFFFD9ETwAyDMDIxLjA0LjEyLjE1LjFwAA==
```

But not gives me the value of the second line (SDFFFtLmlibS50d3Mub2JqZWN0cy5wbGFuDSFIxLDxLjAwADE1FAA==)

Do you know how could I fix it? thanks

Comment: For that data: `{print $NF}`.

Comment: That is, `awk '{print $NF}' file`, you need no `-F '[[:space:]][[:space:]][[:space:]]'` then.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at

```
1   GNFJCOLT   INPET99999   SDFDSFSFLFSDFFFD9ETwAyDMDIxLjA0LjEyLjE1LjFwAA==
2   PARAINIT                SDFFFtLmlibS50d3Mub2JqZWN0cy5wbGFuDSFIxLDxLjAwADE1FAA==
```

I notice that 4rd column content always start in same place, if this does holds true for whole file you might harness `cut -b`, if your file is named `file.txt` then `cut -b 29- file.txt` should produce desired output